# MS SQL Server 2012 reusing numbers

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I have a very high transaction database
I have multiple sequences to unique generate numbers for different outlets.

One of the outlets started receiving errors because i have a unique constraint on a table to prevent duplicates.
The sequence that generates the numbers rolled back more than 10 numbers.

I can afford for this to happen again because it stops sales and I currently have over 70 sequences and going to added more as the months go by.

Has anyone ever experienced this before and how can i stop this from happening in the future ?

any help would be appreciated .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a [known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/790161/next-value-for-sequence-can-fail-to-return-proper-next-value) in some circumstances.

As far as I can see, you need to use [NO CACHE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110).aspx) so numbers cannot be reused

Comment: Thank you but I am concerned that using No CACHE may affect performance. I will do more research on this. Thanks again